# How to align last item to right in the grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,auto);
  justify-content:left;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.child3{
  margin-left:auto;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="child1">
  child-1
</div>
<div class="child2">
  child-2
</div>
<div class="child3">
  child-3
</div>
</div>
```

I need to align the 3rd item(yellow bg ) to right aligned. is it possible with grid layout?

Comment: `grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif => child2 occupies all space between 1 and 3, which I do not required

Comment: then `grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr auto` and you place the child3 at the last column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.container{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows:1fr;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "a b c d";
  justify-content:left;
  border:1px solid red;
}

.child3{
  grid-area: d;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="child1">
  child-1
</div>
<div class="child2">
  child-2
</div>
<div class="child3">
  child-3
</div>
</div>
```